# Multiple API calls from Angular, Multiple Instances of EF Core - Thread Safe?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have an Angular 7 front end which calls through to a .NET Core Web API, which essentially transposes my EF-Core layer. I am new to Angular but essentially I am getting the following error:

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. 
This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext
```

I am making 2 calls, 1 to get a count of records, another to check if the weeks data has been processed. The count is being used in the nav, the week data is being called from another module.

***Angular Service***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsumerService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || { };
  }

  private endpoint = environment.API_URL + "/webapi/Report/";
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };

  getCount(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.endpoint + 'items/count').pipe(map(this.extractData));
    }

    getOverview(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(this.endpoint + 'Overview').pipe(map(this.extractData));
    }
```

***Navbar Module***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ConsumerService } from "../../services/consumer.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-navbar",
  templateUrl: "./navbar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./navbar.component.css"]
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  counts: any;
  new: any;
  modified: any;
  discontinued: any;

  constructor(public consumer: ConsumerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.consumer.getCount().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.counts = data;
      this.new = this.counts.New;
      this.discontinued = this.counts.Deleted;
      this.modified = this.counts.Modified;
    });

  }
}
```

***Controller Module***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { ConsumerService } from "../../services/consumer.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-controller",
  templateUrl: "./controller.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./controller.component.css"]
})
export class ControllerComponent implements OnInit {

  counts: any;
  new: any;
  modified: any;
  discontinued: any;
  currentWeek: any;
  allWeeks$: any;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(public consumer: ConsumerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      searching: false,
      paging: false,
      processing: true,
      ordering: false
    };

    this.consumer.getOverview().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.counts = data["count"];
      this.new = this.counts.New;
      this.discontinued = this.counts.Deleted;
      this.modified = this.counts.Modified;

      this.currentWeek = data["latestEntry"];


      this.allWeeks$ = data["allEntries"];
      this.dtTrigger.next();

    });

  }

}
```

***.NET Core API Controller***

```
namespace ReportApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("webapi/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ReportController : ControllerBase
    {
        private StagedReporting _reporting;

        public ReportController(StagedReporting reporting)
        {
            _reporting = reporting;
        }

        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        [HttpGet("Overview")]
        public object Overview()
        {
            var response = new OverviewViewModel();

            response.LatestEntry = _reporting.GetLatestEntry();
            response.AllEntries = _reporting.GetAllEntries().OrderByDescending(a => a.id).ToList();
            response.Count = _reporting.GetChangeCount();

            return response;
        }

        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        [HttpGet("items/count")]
        public object Report()
        {
             response = new Dictionary<string, int>();
             response = _reporting.GetChangeCount();
             return response;
        }
    }
```

***Staged Reporting***

```
    public class StagedReporting : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed;
        private IItemsDbContext _itemsDbContext;
        private entry _entry;

        public StagedReporting (IItemsDbContext itemsDbContext)
        {
            _itemsDbContext= itemsDbContext;
            _entry = GetLatestEntry();
        }

        public entry GetLatestEntry()
        {
            return _itemsDbContext.entry.OrderByDescending(e => e.id).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public List<entry> GetAllEntries()
        {
            return _itemsDbContext.entry.OrderBy(e => e.id).ToList();
        }

        public virtual Dictionary<string, int> GetChangeCount()
        {
            var response = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            response.Add("New", GetNewEntries().Count);
            response.Add("Modified", GetModifiedEntries().Count);
            response.Add("Deleted", GetDeletedEntries().Count);

            return response;
        }

        public virtual List<ReportStagedImportNewEntries> GetNewEntries()
        {
            var newEntries = new List<ReportStagedImportNewEntries>();

            if (!_entry.processed.HasValue)
            {
                newEntries.AddRange(_itemsDbContext.ReportStagedImportNewEntries);
            }

            return newEntries;
        }

}
```

Obviously, I want to be able to make these calls from Angular without a problem, but as mentioned above, I am getting the error due to EF being thread safe.

When I remove the call from the navbar the issue stops. Any suggestions on how to improve my code, receive the results of both calls?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to create an instance of `ItemsDbContext` per request, how is it registered, as a singleton?

Comment: @PeterBons funnily enough, I just registered the StagedReporting as a transient rather than a singleton which has fixed my issue

Comment: That makes sense, because it will then be created per request (and so is the ItemsDbContext  instance).

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question. I was creating my StagedReporting as a Singleton, I changed this to Transient and thus created one per request and this has fixed my issue.